# How do I append character gotten from loop to a string and return the value of the string as my output

Tags: c, char, c-strings, uppercase, function-definition

I wanted to return characters as a single string after making each character uppercase in C language (Not using printf or putchar). The aim is to return the value of the string after adding each character

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_upcase(char *param_1)
{
    int j = 0;
    char *result = "";
    char *str;
    
    while (j < strlen(param_1))
    {
        char toupper = param_1[j];
        if(toupper >= 'a'){
            // putchar(toupper - 32);
            *str = toupper - 32;
            strncat(result, &toupper -32, 1);
            putchar(*str);
        }else {
        // putchar(toupper);
        *str = toupper;
         strncat(result, &toupper, 1);
         putchar(*str);
        }
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function implementation does not make sense.

Firstly if the function does not change the source string then its parameter  should be declared with qualifier `const`

```
char * my_upcase( const char *param_1 );
```

This declaration

```
char *result = "";
```

declares a pointer to a string ;iteral. You may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

This declaration

```
char *str;
```

declares an uninitialized pointer that has an indeterminate value. Dereferencing such a pointer results in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate dynamically a character array and copy into it characters of the source string converted to the upper case.

Using the function `strncat` is inefficient.

And do not use magic numbers like `32`. Instead use the standard C function `toupper` declared in the header `<ctype.h>`

For example the function can be defined the following way

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//...

char * my_upcase( const char *param_1 )
{
    char *result = malloc( strlen( param_1 ) + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *p = result;

        while ( ( *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*param_1 ) ) != '\0' )
        {
            ++p;
            ++param_1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Taking your comment to my answer

> Thank you for your response. However, I am not allowed to change this
> declaration char * my_upcase( const char *param_1 ); and the platform
> will not allow toupper method

it seems the function must change the original passed string. In this case it can be defined the following way

```
char * my_upcase( char *param_1 )
{
    for ( char *p = param_1; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( 'a' <= *p && *p <= 'z' )
        {
            *p = *p - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }

    return param_1;
}
```